# What's wrong with my palindrome finding function?

Tags: string-manipulation, dictionary, palindrome

I'm trying to find the palindromes in the dictionary, but my output isn't giving me all of them.

I have this so far

```
Palindrome[] := DictionaryLookup[y_ /; (y == StringReverse[y])]
Palindrome[]
```

And my the output just it gives me `{a,I}`.  What's wrong with my input?  I don't see it.

---

Thanks.

Comment: Two underscores after your y should help

Comment: `Palindrome[] := DictionaryLookup[y__ /; (y == StringReverse[y])]`

Comment: Ah okay thanks.  Why did I need two underscores?  I read the reference on wolfram, but I'm not sure how it applies here.

Comment: A single underscore is for a single character, and double underscore is for one or more.

Comment: So by character, you mean the double underscore is applied to the y and that would give me more than a one  letter word?

Comment: Normally, y__ would stand for a sequence of one or more arguments, but the syntax description of DictionaryLookup clearly states it expects a *string pattern*. You can read everything about string patterns in the Details section of `StringExpression`.

Comment: `Select[DictionaryLookup[], PalindromeQ] // AbsoluteTiming` and `Cases[DictionaryLookup[], _?PalindromeQ] // AbsoluteTiming` provide comparable timing these are roughly twice as slow compared to `Palindrome[]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to search for multi-letter palindromes, two underscores are needed as described in the [help for string patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/StringPatterns.html):

```
Palindrome[] := DictionaryLookup[y__ /; (y == StringReverse[y])]
```

Now, Mathematica is probably not good enough to come up with [lyrical palindromes](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/Bob-lyrics-Weird-Al-Yankovic/64A208DBB08E381D48256D2E000AABEA).

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* 10.3 introduced the function [`PalindromeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PalindromeQ.html), which can be utilized here

```
palindrome[] := DictionaryLookup[y__ /; PalindromeQ[y]]

palindrome[]
```

> ```
> {"a", "aha", "aka", "bib", "bob", "boob", "bub", "CFC", "civic", "dad", "deed", "deified",
>  "did", "dud", "DVD", "eke", "ere", "eve", "ewe", "eye", "gag", "gig", "huh", "I", 
>  "kayak", "kook", "level", "ma'am", "madam", "mam", "MGM", "minim", "mom", "mum", "nan", 
>  "non", "noon", "nun", "oho", "pap", "peep", "pep", "pip", "poop", "pop", "pup", "radar", 
>  "redder", "refer", "repaper", "reviver", "rotor", "sagas", "sees", "seres", "sexes", 
>  "shahs", "sis", "solos", "SOS", "stats", "stets", "tat", "tenet", "TNT", "toot", "tot", 
>  "tut", "wow", "WWW"}
> ```

Unfortunately this is much slower (≈ 10 times slower) than using

```
DictionaryLookup[y__ /; y === StringReverse[y]]
```

but can be also used with the option `IgnoreCase -> True`:

```
DictionaryLookup[y__ /; PalindromeQ[y, IgnoreCase -> True]]
```

> ```
> {"a", "Abba", "Ada", "aha", "aka", "Ana", "Anna", "Ava", "bib", "bob", "Bob", "boob", 
>  "bub", "CFC", "civic", "dad", "deed", "deified", "did", "dud", "DVD", "Ede", "eke", 
>  "ere", "eve", "Eve", "ewe", "eye", "gag", "gig", "Hannah", "huh", "I", "kayak", "kook", 
>  "Laval", "level", "ma'am", "madam", "Malayalam", "mam", "MGM", "minim", "mom", "mum", 
>  "nan", "Nan", "non", "noon", "nun", "oho", "Ono", "Otto", "pap", "peep", "pep", "pip", 
>  "poop", "pop", "pup", "radar", "redder", "refer", "repaper", "reviver", "rotor", "sagas",
>  "Salas", "sees", "seres", "sexes", "shahs", "sis", "solos", "SOS", "stats", "stets", 
>  "tat", "tenet", "Tet", "Tevet", "TNT", "toot", "tot", "tut", "Tut", "wow", "WWW"}
> ```

However, for this using

```
DictionaryLookup[y__ /; ToLowerCase@y === StringReverse[ToLowerCase@y]]
```

is much faster.

Comment: interesting. why does the official implementation perform worse than the user-defined one?

Comment: @sunt05 `PalindromeQ` has additional overheads, especially for strings.

Comment: @sunt05 and it seems, many new functions, at least at first, perform worse, than what could be user-defined in previous versions. One example is `ContainsAll` and related functions.